# Is it possible to federate Azure Active Directory using Google Cloud Identity with SAML SSO?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, saml

I know that it is possible to do this without SAML by using B2B SSO.

However I'd like to know if there's the possibility to sign on to azure ad using google but with SAML SSO.

Comment: If you mean to do SAML based WebSSO between Azure AD and Google, then the answer is yes. Google can act as the SAML IdP and Azure AD as the SAML SP

Answer (score 0):

According to the following GCP document [click here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on) , you are able to federating Azure Active Directory using Google Cloud Identity with SAML SSO. For detailed information regarding the configuration please follow the above mentioned link.